# LISP to c# conversion

Tags: c#, lisp

Please help convert a small LISP code to c#

```
(mult s (diff (const 1) (mult (ramp 1) (ramp 1))))
```

Comment: What the heck is this Lisp code supposed to do?

Comment: Performs some calculations:)
Need help such as in
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481803/converting-some-lisp-to-c)

Answer (score 6):

LISP and C# both use prefix function call notation. The big differences are that in LISP you put parentheses around the whole expression and whitespace delimits parameters, while in C# you put the open paren *after* the function name and *commas* delimit parameters. Here's how you'd write your expression in C# (assuming the same function names):

```
mult(s, diff(const(1), mult(ramp(1), ramp(1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `var result =  s*(1-Ramp(1)*Ramp(1));`
But I have no idea what is the ramp function doing:)